# PHP error for login

Tags: php, android

im creating a login for android in php but when the variable "nombre" dont connect with the table:

```
<?php

include_once 'connection.php';

    class User {

        private $db;
        private $connection;

        function __construct() {
            $this -> db = new DB_Connection();
            $this -> connection = $this->db->getConnection();
        }

        public function does_user_exist($id,$password)
        {
            $query = "Select * from users where nombre='$nombre' and password = '$password' ";
            $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
                $json['success'] = 'Bienvenido '.$nombre;
                echo json_encode($json);
                mysqli_close($this -> connection);
            }else{
                $query = "insert into USERS (nombre, password) values ( '$nombre','$password')";
                $inserted = mysqli_query($this -> connection, $query);
                if($inserted == 1 ){
                    $json['success'] = 'Acount created';
                }else{
                    $json['error'] = 'Contraseña incorrecta';
                }
                echo json_encode($json);
                mysqli_close($this->connection);
            }

        }

    }


    $user = new User();
    if(isset($_POST['nombre'],$_POST['password'])) {
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if(!empty($nombre) && !empty($password)){

            $encrypted_password = md5($password);
            $user-> does_user_exist($id,$password);

        }else{
            echo json_encode("you must type both inputs");
        }

    }

?>
```

The error is in $_POST['nombre'] but i dont know why the database code dont get "nombre" but i can get password, the code is for an android login       `if(isset($_POST['nombre'],$_POST['password']))`
But this code also works well, they only thing i wanted to do is to return to the app the id instead the email to save it in a variable

```
<?php

include_once 'connection.php';

class User {

    private $db;
    private $connection;

    function __construct() {
        $this -> db = new DB_Connection();
        $this -> connection = $this->db->getConnection();
    }

    public function does_user_exist($email,$password)
    {
        $query = "Select * from users where email='$email' and password = '$password' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
            $json['success'] = 'Bienvenido '.$email;
            echo json_encode($json);
            mysqli_close($this -> connection);
        }else{
            $query = "insert into USERS (email, password) values ( '$email','$password')";
            $inserted = mysqli_query($this -> connection, $query);
            if($inserted == 1 ){
                $json['success'] = 'Acount created';
            }else{
                $json['error'] = 'Contraseña incorrecta';
            }
            echo json_encode($json);
            mysqli_close($this->connection);
        }

    }

}


$user = new User();
if(isset($_POST['email'],$_POST['password'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if(!empty($email) && !empty($password)){

        $encrypted_password = md5($password);
        $user-> does_user_exist($email,$password);

    }else{
        echo json_encode("you must type both inputs");
    }

}
```

The db connection code for android

```
 request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        if (jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("success")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + jsonObject.getString("success"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + jsonObject.getString("error"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: `if(!empty($nombre)` - Where do you ever set a variable called `$nombre`?  You seem to have inconsistent variable names throughout other parts of your code too.  Variable names are important.

Comment: Keep in mind that your code is wide open to SQL injection, which is a common source of errors, and you're not checking for errors from the database.

Comment: 1. MD5 is not encryption, it is a weak cryptographic hash function. 2. When saving a password verifier just using a hash function such as MD5 (or stronger) is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Better yet use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `Argon2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `$id` instead of `$nombre`, change your code like this

```
<?php

include_once 'connection.php';

class User {

    private $db;
    private $connection;

    function __construct() {
        $this -> db = new DB_Connection();
        $this -> connection = $this->db->getConnection();
    }

    public function does_user_exist($id,$password)
    {
        $query = "Select * from users where nombre='$id' and password = '$password' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
            $json['success'] = 'Bienvenido '.$id;
            echo json_encode($json);
            mysqli_close($this -> connection);
        }else{
            $query = "insert into USERS (nombre, password) values ( '$id','$password')";
            $inserted = mysqli_query($this -> connection, $query);
            if($inserted == 1 ){
                $json['success'] = 'Acount created';
            }else{
                $json['error'] = 'Contraseña incorrecta';
            }
            echo json_encode($json);
            mysqli_close($this->connection);
        }

    }

}


$user = new User();
if(isset($_POST['nombre'],$_POST['password'])) {
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if(!empty($nombre) && !empty($password)){

        $encrypted_password = md5($password);
        $user-> does_user_exist($nombre,$password);

    }else{
        echo json_encode("you must type both inputs");
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: get the same error, its like the php dont reconogcise the variable id or nombre, but if i change nombre for email(another variable from the table) it works perfectly.

Comment: Yes i got the same error and if i add `else{
  $json['success'] = 'Bienvenido '.$id;
  echo json_encode($json);
  mysqli_close($this -> connection);
 }
` to the code at the end its login me so it means that the error in in if(isset($_POST['id'],$_POST['password']))

Comment: are you sure if the key you are passing from android end is `id` itself, or is it something else(is it `nombre`?)

Comment: you should be adding your code with the question and not in the answer, also post the code where you post params to your endpoint